# Maven build problem: Installed external Maven 3.6 yet getting build error for plugin 2.5

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and JDK 1.8. I have created a Maven project in eclipse. The in built maven that comes with eclipse has a version 3.0.4. There was an error in creating the maven project saying

```
"Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5".
```

But the folder structure was created. Since the inbuilt maven within eclipse was not able to build it. I downloaded and setup full maven from the maven.apache.org. I verified the same by running the command `mvn -v` which showed the version of Maven that I have installed i.e. 3.6.
Then I added a java class under `Maven_Project_Root/src/main/java`. Then tried to build it. Again received the following error:

```
"Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5"
```

-It will be much appreciated if somebody can help.

Comment: First try to build on plain command line and very important with a most recent version of Maven and not a version which is eight years old ...furthermore put the whole output into the post cause I suppose you are accessing central repository via http instead of https ....and furthermore Update your eclipse version cause Kepler is about seven years old ....

Answer (score 0):

The Maven server do not support HTTP anymore. You must configure the maven repositories with HTTPS url's in your local maven configuration file, in your home folder yourname/.m2/settings.xml.

Here is an example that you may copy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>artifactory</id>
         <repositories>
            <repository>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
               </snapshots>
               <id>central</id>
               <name>libs-release</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
               <snapshots />
               <id>snapshots</id>
               <name>libs-snapshot</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
         </repositories>
         <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
               </snapshots>
               <id>central</id>
               <name>plugins-release</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
               <snapshots />
               <id>snapshots</id>
               <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
         </pluginRepositories>         
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: My /myHome/.m2 directory does not have any settings.xml file. It only has a repository directory. Is there anything wrong in my installation?

Comment: No that is Ok. If there is no such file, then Maven uses default settings. You can simply create the file with any text editor.